# AWS Cloudsearch NET or Javascript - Couldn't access to 2011-02-01 Domain for Seach Request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm taking my first steps on AWS Cloudsearch (I Need to use the developers tools for CloudSearch)

I Need to access to the following URL:
https://search-memtestsearch-ra5knmztzu6iq4ntytlxkntqty.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2011-02-01/search?bq=subjectfirstname:%27alex%27&return-fields=subjectlastname,subjectfirstname&results-type=json

But both APIs (NET & Javascript) try to access to:
https://search-memtestsearch-ra5knmztzu6iq4ntytlxkntqty.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?bq=subjectfirstname:%27alex%27&return-fields=subjectlastname,subjectfirstname&results-type=json

I don´t now how I could access to "/2011-02-01" domain instead of "/2013-01-01" domain... 
I know that this is related to the version, but i donn´t know how i could access; also i can´t find examples for this.

I'm going crazy :)

This is the code that i use for NET:

```
        String queryUrl = @"http://search-memtestsearch-ra5knmztzu6iq4ntytlxkntqty.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com";
        AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient searchClient = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(queryUrl);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.Query = .....
        searchRequest.QueryParser =....
        SearchResponse searchResponse = searchClient.Search(searchRequest);
```

And this is the one for Javascript:

```
            var csd = new AWS.CloudSearchDomain({
              endpoint: 'http://search-memtestsearch-ra5knmztzu6iq4ntytlxkntqty.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com',
              apiVersion: '2011-02-01',
              region: 'us-east-1'
            });
            var params = {...}
            csd.search(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err){ console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                }else{console.log(data);           // successful response
            }});
```

Could anybody help me with one example?
Thanks in advance

Sebastian